# Designing a database for a weekly time schedule - speed vs space

Tags: sql-server, database-design, performance, query-performance

I need to "store" a weekly time schedule as compactly as possible.  The schedules are in 15-minute increments.  In a 24 hour period that would give me 96 time slots.  Midnight is 00, 0600 is 24, 1800 is 72 and 2345 is 95.

I need to store 7 days of information per row SO...  Lookup speed vs space-wise, is it more efficient to create a row with 14 SMALLINT columns (start time and end time for each day) or 1 column concatenating padded numbers?  (IE. 2472247224722472247224722472)

There could be millions of rows, so I want to try to reuse common schedules.  This means when someone creates a schedule, I want to look up the schedules that have already been created to find a match and use the match's ID if I can find one.  If not, I'll create a new row.  Would using 14 AND statements on smallints be faster than a CHAR column lookup?  Is there an even better way to do this?

Comment: The idea of concatenating things is a horrible idea. No way to easily look through things to find common schedules not to mention that it would be almost impossible to understand it when you came back to look at it in 6 months time.

Comment: I'm afraid there's simply not enough information here to answer your question - could you include table DDL and some sample queries? Otherwise I'm not sure how we can tell which is more efficient.

Comment: It's not as hard as it looks, each 4-char block represents a padded start and end time (2 chars each) for a single day, 7 blocks per record.  28 chars total.  Comparing  weekly schedules would mean comparing 28-char strings vs splitting this up into 14 smallint columns (day_1_on, day_1_off, day_2_on...day_7_off) and trying to compare all 14 columns simultaneously to see if there is a match.  Storage-wise the 14 columns would probably be smaller because it's only 8 bits per column vs 28 chars @ 8 bits each.

Comment: Honestly, store this info a table. You only need to know the day of week and the time. DAY is deterministic or you could use DATEPART and this would be very small and easily SARGABLE. Oh, you could could compare this by BIN collation, that can improve speed. But test of course.

Comment: To gather more interest for this question, you might consider adding some DDL and DML statements to show what you’ve done so far and help people.